# How to access php URL via curl on Mac Terminal

Tags: php, terminal

I've a php file which I've hosted on some server, now I want to access the output of URL via curl like:

```
curl -s  http://ankur.serve.qa.vdopia.com/getTag.php?type=vanilla&tag=master
[1] 81246
**vanilla4.9.8-2**
```

I am getting hell lot of things but the actual output which is vanilla4.9.8-2 comes little late and as soon as I hit enter after typing curl command, it just shows me the process id and goes in back ground. How do I get the output without taking the command in background.

here is whole code of php:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$type = $_GET['type'];
$tag = $_GET['tag'];

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if($type=='portal')
{
    if($tag=='' || $tag=='master')
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://portal.vdopia.com/version.txt?'.uniqid());  
        $output = curl_exec($ch);  
        curl_close($ch); 

        echo $output;
    }
}
else if ($type=='vanilla')
{
    if($tag=='' || $tag=='master')
    {
        echo 'checking';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://serve.vdopia.com/version.txt?'.uniqid());  
        $output = curl_exec($ch);  
        curl_close($ch); 

        echo $output;
    }
}

exit();
```

Answer (score 5):

The `&` in your curl command sends curl (or any shell command) into the background. You need to escape `&` to remove this special meaning for shell. Just executing your command like this solves the problem:

```
curl -s 'http://ankur.serve.qa.vdopia.com/getTag.php?type=vanilla&tag=master'
```

Outputs:

```
vanilla4.9.8-21
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to quote your link as follows:

```
curl -s 'http://ankur.serve.qa.vdopia.com/getTag.php?type=vanilla&tag=master'
```

in shell, the trailing ampersand `&` symbol make shell run the command in background and returning process status, it's kind of asynchronous running of the command;

Answer (score 2):

You can try curl -s "http://qa.vdopia.com/qa/mayank/test.php?type=vanilla&tag=master"

with "" it should work